# Firebase orderbychild not Working progerly

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

ref.orderByChild("name") This Should Order Like 1,2,3,4,11 But It Order Like This 1,11,2,3,4

This Is My Code To Order.

```
ref.orderByChild("points").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()!
```

Firebase structure:

[image]

Comment: Please post your database structure.

Comment: I think orderbychild is not the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

"name" is described as a String not an Integer in your db structure so you are getting orderByChild in the correct order.

For example, try this code in Dartpad....that is how Firebase is retrieving your data:

```
void main() {
  var intList = [0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 8, 17, 11];
  intList.sort();
  print(intList);

  var tringList = ['0', '1', '5', '2', '3', '8', '17', '11'];
  tringList.sort();
  print(tringList);
}
```

Output is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 17]
[0, 1, 11, 17, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

You need to change "name" to an integer on your database to get the order your require.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so please upvote and mark it as the answer in order to encourage people to continue answering your questions. Thanks